# Numerical integration of experimental data set

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I am working on the following integral, where f(x) and x correspond to a list of data points, f(x) being the experimental reading at a time x.

$\int_{0}^{100}\left (  \frac{30 - f(x)}{100 - x}\right )dx$

I know how to calculate a definite integral when it is simply the area under a simple function, say if we were just looking at the integral of f(x). However I am not sure how to approach this. Fitting a polynomial curve to the f(x) points is also not an allowed option.

Can someone please guide me as to how to do this, with Matlab or Python (or really any code)?

Comment: "Fitting a polynomial curve to the f(x) points is also not an allowed option": why ?

Comment: Is using Riemann sum allowed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum?

Comment: @rtybase yes certainly, were you meaning something along this lines of the g(x) in the first answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you can integrate $f(x)$, you can do it using similar method by letting $$g(x)=\frac{30-f(x)}{100-x}$$

You need to pay attention to your test data at $x=100$ to see if it is a singular point.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! So essentially create a new list g(x) and integrate that?

Answer (score 0):

Fitting a polynomial curve to $f$ is indeed an option, however, $g(x) := \frac{30 - f(x)}{100 -x}$ is already a rational function, so rational interpolation is probably a better option. In C++, you can use Boost's [barycentric rational interpolator](https://github.com/boostorg/math/blob/develop/include/boost/math/interpolators/barycentric_rational.hpp), but make sure that $\lim_{x\to 100} g(x)$ is finite, or it's very likely that the result will be nonsense.

Once you have the rational interpolant, use [double exponential](https://github.com/boostorg/math/pull/66) or Gauss-Konrod quadrature.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Matlab open-source toolbox:

http://www.chebfun.org/examples/approx/EquispacedData.html

http://www.chebfun.org/docs/guide/guide02.html